# Is there a .NET 4.0 replacement for StreamReader.ReadLineAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm stuck with .NET 4.0 on a project. StreamReader offers no Async or Begin/End version of ReadLine. The underlying Stream object has BeginRead/BeginEnd but these take a byte array so I'd have to implement the logic for reading line by line.

Is there something in the 4.0 Framework to achieve this?

Comment: You could just do the reading in a background thread. .NET 4 still has TPL, threads, and BackgroundWorkers.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `ReadLineAsync()` is mainly useful if you have other related features, particularly `async`/`await`. Are you using the Async CTP or Async Targeting Pack for .NET 4.0? If not, what is your plan for using a method like `ReadLineAsync()`? Note that if .NET itself already had something like `ReadLineAsync()`, they probably wouldn't have added it in 4.5. You or someone else will have to write, or will have to have written it already.

Comment: If all you want is _some_ implementation of `ReadLineAsync()`, you can just copy [the .NET version from 4.5](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,884afa7bffa068d0). It's open source, after all.

Comment: @PeterDuniho No, it's not open source. Click "License" at the top of your link. The exact same code may be made available by MS elsewhere under an open source license, but not there.

Comment: @PeterDuniho F# Async.

Comment: @hvd: well, if you want to be extra super special careful, I guess you could copy the exact implementation from the official Git repository: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO/src/System/IO/StreamReader.cs. I find the referencesource.microsoft.com site to be easier to navigate, but the code is essentially the same in either place.

Comment: The reference code implementation contains await and also dozens of other stuff which he doesn't need.

Comment: @mybirthname: by that logic, we shouldn't be calling the .NET implementation ever. After all, it has all that stuff "we don't need". Personally, if given the choice between copying an existing implementation that is overkill for my needs, and wasting time rewriting the essentials myself, I'm generally going with the existing implementation. That said, the bottom line here is: no, .NET 4.0 does not itself include anything like this. You either write it yourself, or copy it from somewhere else. Like from the open sourced .NET code.

Comment: @Asik: if you're using F#, you should not find it that difficult to write this yourself, using the async features for `Stream`, since F# already has a lot of the async stuff built in even targeting .NET 4. The `TaskFactory.FromAsync()` method exists in .NET 4, which does all the heavy lifting for wrapping `Stream.BeginRead()`, etc. in a `Task` you can await on.

Comment: Yes, I did mention I could implement this using BeginRead/EndRead in the question.

Comment: @Asik I wrote full example how to do it without blocking the UI thread. Check it. This should simulate async/await

Comment: "I'm stuck with .NET 4.0 on a project" That should not be the case. Using .NET 4.0 is akin to using Windows XP today. If it doesn't work, you have no one to blame except yourself.

Comment: @Aron but it *is* the case, and you have no idea why, and your patronizing is as pointless as it is unhelpful.

Comment: @Asik I phrased it wrongly. I meant "When it breaks, no one will be responsible, since .NET has been EOL for over a year now. I worked in a couple of multi-nationals that did the whole "Extended Support" thing, in an industry known for having a turning circle measured in decades (we still have a couple of mainframes). Yet we have replaced .net 4.0 (late I might add) already.

Comment: @Asik The only valid reason I can think of is "Windows XP doesn't support .net 4.5". At which point the question become "Why are you using XP, its been EOL for over 2 years now"...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task`. You don't specify other part of your code so I don't know what you want to do. I advise you to avoid using `Task.Wait` because this is blocking the UI thread and waiting for the task to finish, which became not really async ! If you want to do some other action after the file is readed in the task, you can use `task.ContinueWith`.

**Here full example, how to do it without blocking the UI thread**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"FILE PATH";
        Task<string[]> task = Task.Run<string[]>(() => ReadFile(filePath));

        bool stopWhile = false;

        //if you want to not block the UI with Task.Wait() for the result
        // and you want to perform some other operations with the already read file
        Task continueTask = task.ContinueWith((x) => {
            string[] result = x.Result; //result of readed file

            foreach(var a in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }

            stopWhile = true;
            });

        //here do other actions not related with the result of the file content
        while(!stopWhile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        }

    }

    public static string[] ReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();
        string line = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                lines.Add(line);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File Readed");
        return lines.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) to do some of the async behavior you're trying to do.

Wrap the synchronous method in a task:

```
var asyncTask = Task.Run(() => YourMethod(args, ...));
var asyncTask.Wait(); // You can also Task.WaitAll or other methods if you have several of these that you want to run in parallel.
var result = asyncTask.Result;
```

If you need to do this a lot for StreamReader, you can then go on to make this into an extension method for StreamReader if you want to simulate the regular async methods.  Just take care with the error handling and other quirks of using the TPL.

Comment: Sure, but I'd rather not block a ThreadPool thread. I was assuming StreamReader.ReadLineAsync() could do this without actually blocking a thread.